# iOS UITextView doesn't allow UITableViewCell to be selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have a UITableViewCell, and inside of it, i have a UITextView with some text, and it must remain scrollable so i can't remove the user interaction in it.

But the problem is, when i tap the screen, this cell must be selectable as well. Since the UITextView is in front of the cell touch area i'm unable to do that.

I've try to place a UITapGestureRecognizer into the UITextView inside the cell class but i don't know which method to call to select the cell, ending on the UITableView delegate (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) in the main class.

Does Anyone can help me with that, or have other ideas how i can sort this out?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
//CUSTOM CELL CODE

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_MEDIUM size:14];
    self.title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:181/255.0 green:181/255.0 blue:179/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_LIGHT_ITA size:13];
    self.text.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236/255.0 green:220/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchAction:)];
    [self.text addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

-(void)touchAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{
    NSLog(@"Touch");
}

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this way ?

without disabling textView's user interaction set UITextView's delegate, implement UITextViewDelegate's textViewShouldBeginEditing method like this

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:yourCellIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    return NO;
}
```

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewShouldBeginEditing%3a) says "When the user performs an action that would normally initiate an editing session, the text view calls this method first to see if editing should actually proceed."

Comment: also without using UITapGestureRecognzer

Comment: It is working so far, but the thing is selectRowAtIndexPath Method doesn't trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath Delegate. I'm still trying to figure it out. As soon as i found out i'll come back here. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Since **selectRowAtIndexPath** doesn't trigger the delegate methods i've called myself `[self tableView:self.table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` and it worked! i don't know if it is the right way, but is solved... **Thanks a lot for the help!**

Comment: yeah, right!  selectRow only selects row, there is nothing wrong to call it yourself. I'm glad to help )